# Setup moq with Caliburn event aggregator for a method wrapping PublishOnUIThreadAsync

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq, caliburn.micro

From my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45954868/8373489), I've learned that I have to do `Mock.Setup` to let the `eventAggregatorMoq` know about the return data.

```
public void Navigate() {
    eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new MyEvent(5));
}
```

The following was working fine for covering the above wrapper method which was not `await`ing and returning `void`.

```
eventAggregatorMock.Verify(_ => _.Publish(It.IsAny<MyEvent>(), 
                                It.IsAny<Action<System.Action>>()), Times.Once);
```

So, how do I setup in case if I'm awaiting on my method which returns Task.

```
public async Task Navigate() {
    await eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new MyEvent(5));
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: What is the error you encountered? It is also assumed that you provided a setup for the method in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `PublishOnUIThreadAsync` extension method, which returns a Task

```
/// <summary>
/// Publishes a message on the UI thread asynchrone.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventAggregator">The event aggregator.</param>
/// <param name="message">The message instance.</param>
public static Task PublishOnUIThreadAsync(this IEventAggregator eventAggregator, object message) {
    Task task = null;
    eventAggregator.Publish(message, action => task = action.OnUIThreadAsync());
    return task;
}
```

You would notice that the Task is assigned within the action being executed by `Publish`. You would need to invoke the action in order for the task to be assigned by making sure that the delegate/action is called. You can do that within a callback of the mocked method.

The following minimal example demonstrates how to do that. Note how `Publish` is setup with the call back to invoke the passed in Action argument.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _EventAggregator_Should_Publish_OnUIThread() {
        //Arrange
        MyEvent navigateEvent = null;
        var eventAggregatorMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
        eventAggregatorMock
            .Setup(x => x.Publish(It.IsAny<MyEvent>(), It.IsAny<Action<System.Action>>()))
            .Callback((object message, Action<System.Action> marshal) => {
                navigateEvent = (MyEvent)message;
                marshal(() => { });//Invoking action that would cause task to be assigned
            });
        var sut = new MyClass(eventAggregatorMock.Object);
        //Act
        await sut.Navigate();
        //Assert
        navigateEvent.Should().NotBeNull();
        eventAggregatorMock.Verify(_ => _.Publish(It.IsAny<MyEvent>(), 
            It.IsAny<Action<System.Action>>()), Times.Once);
    }

    public class MyEvent {
        private int p;

        public MyEvent(int p) {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.p = p;
        }

    }
    public class MyClass {
        IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
        public MyClass(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

        public async Task Navigate() {
            await eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new MyEvent(5));
        }
    }
}
```